# How do I get a set intersection of two std::unordered_map's?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have two `std::unordered_map` instances with 0 or more intersecting keys. I am trying return a new instance of `std::unordered_map` whose keys are the intersection of the keys of `mapA` and `mapB` and whose values at those keys are from `mapA`.

**How can I find the set intersection of these two maps `mapA` and `mapB` while keeping only the values from `mapA`?**

The following provides an example of the results I am trying to achieve:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, double> MapType;

MapType intersectFilter(MapType const & mapA, MapType const & mapB);

int main()
{
    MapType mapA = { {"keyA",  1}, {"keyB", 2} };
    MapType mapB = { {"keyA",  5}, {"keyK", 3} };

    MapType mapC = intersectFilter(mapA, mapB);
    // The resulting `mapC` should be:
    // { {"keyA", 1} }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some implementation based on `std::remove_if()` and an appropriate lambda function maybe?

Comment: Do you actually want `mapA` or `mapB` to be mutated?  If so then you really don't want to remove anything, you want to copy the common keys.

Comment: If you want to return a new set, then `std::copy_if` would help you copy from one if they exist in the other, but `std::set_intersection` already does that.

Comment: @GemTaylor that would work if it were `map`, but `set_intersection ` requires sorted ranges to operate on

Comment: @NathanOliver edited the question to indicate `mapA` and `mapB` should not be mutated. I want to return an entirely new `MapType` instance.

Comment: @Caleth True, using `unordered_map` does cramp you from using `set_intersection`. Can still do the `copy_if` approach to implement an unordered version of set_intersection quite easily though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward implementation is:

```
MapType intersectFilter(const MapType& mapA, const MapType& mapFilter)
{
    MapType result;
    for (const auto& pair: mapA)
    {
        if (mapFilter.find(pair.first) != mapFilter.end())
            result.insert(pair);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've changed type of parameters to const references, since probably you don't want to copy the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't removing entries, you are conditionally copying. That sounds like a job for [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

```
MapType intersectFilter(MapType const & mapA, MapType const & mapFilter)
{
    MapType result;
    auto inserter = std::inserter(result, result.end());
    auto predicate = [&mapFilter](MapType::const_reference item) 
    { return mapFilter.find(item.first) == mapFilter.end(); }; // or mapFilter.contains in C++20
    std::copy_if(mapA.begin(), mapA.end(), inserter, predicate);
    return result;
}
```